# How to create a list of unique strings, and print that list in a field using ArcGIS Pro field calculator

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, list, unique-value

I have a landcover polygon that I spatially joined to a soils polygon.  This left me with many duplicate soil types in each row of the landcover polygon.  I would like to summarize the soil types to only show a list of unique string values.  How would I go about doing this in the field calculator?

[image: I would like to remove duplicate soil types in each cell]

Comment: This isn't really a field calculator task. There are much better ways to do this, but the particulars vary by GIS platform. Please [Edit] the question to specify your platform.

Answer (score 0):

**With Field calculator and python parser:**

Convert the string to a list with split

Convert the list to a set, which cant have duplicates

Join the set into a string

```
def nodups(soilnames):
    return ', '.join(set(soilnames.split(', ')))
```

Call with:

```
nodups(!Soil Names!)
```

Comment: Than you so much.  This has been weighing on me for a few days, and your explanation was very helpful.